# Access protected var of superclass in php

Tags: php, protected, superclass

short question to a little php problem.

```
class topclass {
protected $test;
//....
}

class childclass extends topclass {`
public static function accessVariable(){

//HOW CAN I ACCESS THE $Test VARIABLE OF THE SUPERCLASS HERE?

}...
```

Can somebody help me?

Thx very much in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use `self::$test` or `parent::$test` for static function and `$this->test` for regular function. Protected variables are available within the scope of the extending classes, private variable are not.

The difference between using `self::$test` and `parent::$test` is that if you have overridden `$test` in the child class you would get the overridden value when using `self::$test`.

Of course if you wish to access the property statically, you need to declare it as static (i.e. `protected static $test`).

Comment: `self::test` statement assumes `test` is a class constant